# Azure API Management how to know if request source is from Application Gateway

Tags: azure, authentication, security, azure-application-gateway

We got an Azure API Management with an Azure Application Gateway in front.

If a request is send to API Management via Application Gateway I want to apply an additional Security Policy.

Documentation says "Host Header" is insecure for this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/host-name-preservation#context)

Is the value Context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host the same value and thus insecur too? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables)

Do you see an other / better way to check in a policy if the request is originally redirected from AG?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe IP Address Filter for AG would work. I will proof. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/filter-ip-addresses-when-using-appgw